# Multi-line if statement using all() to compare values in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of lists and many dictionaries. To keep it short, I will include two of them only with limited data:

```
twins = [['John','Mark'],['David', 'Mike']]
gender = {'John': 'male','Mark': 'male','David': 'male','Mike':'male'}
age = {'John': 2,'Mark': 2,'David': 2,'Mike':2}
```

I use the following code to find twins with same gender and age:

```
for t in twins:
    if all(gender.get(t[0])==gender.get(t[1]) for t in twins)
        and all(age.get(t[0])==age.get(t[1]) for t in twins):
        print(t)
```

This works fine in this example but did not seem to find all matches in a very large list of twins.
Is it the right way to do it? How could finding specific values in dictionaries be done differently?

Comment: why looping externally on twins?

Comment: I need it for other statements. E.g.
        totalBenefits = totalBenefits + benefits.get(t[1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
twins = [['John','Mark'],['David', 'Joanna']]
gender = {'John': 'male','Mark': 'male','David': 'male','Mike':'male', 'Joanna':"female"}
age = {'John': 2,'Mark': 2,'David': 2,'Joanna':2}
final_twins = [[name1, name2] for name1, name2 in twins if gender[name1] == gender[name2] and age[name1] == age[name2]]
```

Output:

```
[['John', 'Mark']]
```